# SharePoint List column validation related to another item

Tags: list, formatting, conditional, list-validation

I have a SP list with 3 fields:

- "report type" (choose list "A", "B" or "AB")
- "Type A due date"
- "Type B due date".

  1. I want to set-up column validation for the due date so that "Type A due date" is required only when "A" or "AB" was chosen in the "report type" field. any idea?
  2. Bonus question just coming to me (but I assume I could do it if I find solution to question 1): How to have an alert is a due date is selected while the related report type was not checked?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you using SharePoint Online? are you aware of List Validation settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using list **Validation settings**. use below formula:

```
=IF(OR([report type]="A",[report type]="AB"),IF(ISBLANK([Type A due date]),FALSE,TRUE),TRUE)
```

[Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)).

Comment: Hi Ganesh,Thanks for responding. I just tried this solution (in the List 'validation settings) but it failed bacause I can't use my column "Report type" because it's not a data type supported by the formula (I guess because of possible multiple chooses?).

Comment: Anyway I assume the best is to split the question for report to have one for each type of report. then  your solution should work. I will test this

Comment: Is it a choice field with multiple selection enabled??

Comment: yes, I don't see it in the list of column that can be insert. If I type it I have an error message stating this data type is not supported for this formula..

Comment: If you are using choice field with multiple selection enabled then it will not work. as choice field with multiple selection are not allowed in formulas.

Comment: Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this answer helped you in any way..

Comment: indeed, I just tested and replaced by Radio choose and it works. So I can do it with your formula if I split my reports it two questions.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ganesh!